# Find indexes for a certain character in string

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner in Python and I'm trying to find Indexes for every "o" in this string. This only shows index for first o, while I'm trying to find all of them:

```
besedilo = "Dober dan Slovenija"
    print (besedilo.index("o"))
```

I thought I could use for loop but I'm not quite sure how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(besedilo) if c == 'o']
```

Demo:

```
>>> besedilo = "Dober dan Slovenija"
>>> [i for i, c in enumerate(besedilo) if c == 'o']
[1, 12]
```

The [`str.index()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) also takes an optional `start` argument, the starting index from which to search (defaults to 0), so you *could* build a loop with the last location + 1 to collect all indices:

```
indices = []
next = -1
while True:
    try:
        next = besedilo.index(next + 1)
        indices.append(next)
    except ValueError:
        break
```

If speed is an issue, then this last method is actually the faster option of the two:

```
$ bin/python -m timeit -s "test = 'Dober dan Slovenija'" "indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(test) if c=='o']" 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.51 usec per loop
$ bin/python -m timeit -s "test = 'Dober dan Slovenija'" -s "indices,next=[],-1" "while True:" "    try:" "        next= test.index('o', next+1)" "        indices.append(next)" "    except ValueError: break"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 usec per loop
```

Comment: Is the list comprehension always faster, or only for shorter strings? I would have expected the index method to win for an uncommon character in a long string. Also of course the loop using index works much better than your enumerate solution if the search string is longer than one character.

Comment: @Duncan: both methods have to scan the whole string, and the `str.index()` and `list.append()` method lookups and calls take their toll too with a higher constant cost. I don't have the time right now to do a proper `timeit` trial though; my gut instinct tells me the list comp will win most, if not all cases.

Comment: Never trust your gut. `python -m timeit -s "test = 'Dober dan Slovenija'" "indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(test) if c=='o']"` 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.6 usec per loop `python -m timeit -s "test = 'Dober dan Slovenija'" -s "indices,next=[],-1" "while True:" " try:" "  next= test.index('o', next+1)" "  indices.append(next)" " except ValueError: break"` 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 usec per loop The while loop wins every string I've tried. When I tried with a string of `'x'*1000+'o'` it won by a factor of 182.

Comment: @Duncan: Interesting! Score 1 for actual timing data!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> besedilo = "Dober dan Slovenija"
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(besedilo) if j == 'o']
[1, 12]
```

This will loop through both the string and a sort of counter starting from 0. If a letter matches `'o'`, then the count will be in the list returned by the list comprehension.

Alternatively, you can use the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [i for i, j in itertools.izip(itertools.count(), besedilo) if j == 'o'] # itertools.izip not needed if you are using Python 3
[1, 12]
```

Keep in mind that `enumerate()` is much more efficient :).

Comment: `itertools.izip(itertools.count(), ...)` is not the most efficient alternative to just `enumerate()`..